# Problems with graphic card and processor after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, intel

I have ubuntu 17.04. It was all good until the last update. The system no longer recognizes my integrated GPU and uses intel rather, returning '`unknown`' to `prime-select query`; `prime-select nvidia` returns the following:

```
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'mesa']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', 'nvidia-375']
Info: selecting nvidia-375 for the nvidia profile
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

. Nonetheless when I use nVidia settings to activate the GPU it says i need to logout and then back in, but when I do it's back on intel Kabylake. What's more I got these scripts shown in the photo below during the boot which I think are related to the processor and to the gpu, although all I have found about is how to make them 'not-appearing' rather than a proper fix. In the 'Additional Driver window, even if i chose the proprietary driver, the GPU's name keeps being 'unknown'... If anyone could help me I'd be really grateful.
[image]

PS. the error scripts on the boot appeared after I updated kernel to the version 4.12, but deleting it didn't get rid of the scrips...

Comment: Anyone answers this plz?